# About windows resource data language

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010

Following is from pragmatic programmer book

> I am reading about data languages and it is mentioned about Microsoft
>   has been using data language that can describe menus, widgets, dialog
>   boxes, and other window resources. It is compiled  to generate a data
>   structure.

My question when resource file is compiled what data structure it generates?

Comment: Is there any related Microsoft documentation about it? Its new for me!

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with winforms.  Resources that represent dialogs and menus etc are a feature of native code.  It is ancient, Petzold's "Programming Windows" describes it in detail.

Answer (score 0):

Theseshould point you in the right direction if you are really interested.

File Formats http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648007(v=vs.85).aspx

Resource types http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648009%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Resource structures http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff468906(v=vs.85).aspx

The compiled resource format has been around a long time. I have never needed the details re: the compiled format; I just used them when I needed them.